# Play Framework evolutions in different subprojects

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-evolutions

I have a Play Framework 2.2 project that has different subprojects. Everything worked fine while only one of those subprojects had SQL evolution scripts.

Now, I'm trying to introduce another subproject with a SQL evolution script and I see no way of defining dependencies between them, or even to execute them both, while keeping them in their subprojects (where logically they belong).

So, how can I have evolution scripts in different submodules and have them all execute, respecting dependencies between them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add to **application.conf file** the list of models packages:

> ebean.default = ["models.common.*","models.sub1.*", "models.sub2.*",
>   ...]

And use **dependsOn** in build.sbt like this to get what you need:

lazy val sub1 = project.in(file("modules/sub1"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)
  .dependsOn(common)

***Attention: the sintax is for play framework 2.4***

Comment: Can this be done without using EBean (i.e. just using vanilla evolutions)?

Comment: I'm using 2.5.8 and this is not working for me. Any ideas ?

Comment: At moment, my version is 2.5.9 and it works.

what happens?